# WorkflowRuntime.StopRuntime gets stuck

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, workflow, workflow-foundation

I have a very basic workflow hosted in a windows service (C#, .net 3.5) with a strange problem.

Configuration:

- The runtime and workflow instance is created in the same thread.
- I have a background thread executing Start on the instance in an "endless" loop in order to have it running continuously.

When an exception is thrown from the workflow, I want to clean up and shut down the service. The problem is, that it does not work :)

I have a Stop-method that basically does:

> ...
>   backgroundThread.Join(..);
>   if (workflowRuntime.isStarted)
>     workflowRuntime.StopRuntime();
>   ...

The problem here is workflowRuntime.StopRuntime(). When invoked, it just stucks. No return value, exception or timeout. It just stops. I've also tried to use workFlowInstance.TryUnload(), but same thing. It just stucks.

I've checked the thread id's and it's the same thead in the stop-method that created and started the workflow.

Any ideas at all? If I just skip all the cleaing up of the workflow runtime, the service ends up in a zombie state and can't be shutdown.